# I need to send "userid" in savechangesasync method

Tags: entity-framework, api, asp.net-core

I'm implementing an audit table and i override savechangesasync, but i need to retrieve the userid but i have no access to HttpContextAccessor in my context class because it is in another project in the solution, i want to send it as an argument in the savechangesasync.Ive got two table:
Person{id,name,phone} , and audittable{id,keys,oldvalues,newvalues,date,userid}.

My solution has two projects web where my controllers are , and a data project where context and models clasess are.
I overwrite savechangesasync like this:

```
   public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
            var auditEntries = OnBeforeSaveChanges();
            var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
            await OnAfterSaveChanges(auditEntries);
            return result;
    }
```

await _context.saveChangesAsync(userid)
Or is there any other better way? Thanks

Comment: Why can't you inject the HttpContextAccesser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This interface is located in your Data Project:

```
public interface IUserIdProvider
{
    int UserId { get; }
}
```

This implementation is located in your Web Project:

```
public class UserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public UserIdProvider(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public int UserId
    {
        get
        {
            var nameId = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            return nameId != null ? int.Parse(nameId.Value) : -1;
        }
    }
}
```

I assume you register your services in your Web Project:

```
services.AddScoped<IUserIdProvider, UserIdProvider>();
```

Then in your DbContext, inject the `IUserIdProvider`:

```
public partial class MyDbContext
{
    private IUserIdProvider _userIdProvider;

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, IUserIdProvider userIdProvider) : base(options)
    {
        _userIdProvider = userIdProvider;
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        //do you what you need with _userIdProvider here
        var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ZatchMichael awesome! could you mark my post as the answer?

Comment: @ZatchMichael no worries, you'll get there. to be honest, I actually learned this answer from some other more experienced developer than me haha. I didn't know how to do it either :P